# Lambda functions does not appear on AWS Console when I deploy from VSCode with Serverless Deploy

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

My problem is that if I write the Lambda function in VSCode I cannot deploy it to AWS console.

I have an AWS account and provided credentials to use in VSCode. Just testing the deployment of simple Lambda function to AWS Console with `serverless deploy` command. So far no success. It creates the bucket on S3 and put zip code there.

ConsoleTest function was created manually in AWS Lambda Console.
[image]

My serverless.yml looks like this:

```
service: myservice
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x


functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
         path: users/create
         method: get
```

Result in terminal (I get correctly JSON response)
[image]

I was following the official guide: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/deploying/

Any help, please?

Comment: I think you need to use this command: serverless deploy function --function myFunction

Comment: I tried it also, but it says a) first I need to use serverless deploy or b) no need to update the function. It's up to date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution. 
Problem was that it created the wrong region. I also installed AWS Cli and specified region into a config file, but added region property to the provider. Not sure which one helped, because basically they do the same function.
When I put

```
service: myservice
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: development
  region: eu-central-1
```

Everything started to work correctly and deploy to my AWS console.

Comment: I agree with you, I was facing the same problem, and changing the region fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Change the zone as shown in image.